# How does the kernel knows which "threads"/processes are associated with a process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process, thread

As I have read, a "thread" in Linux is just a process.

Say that a process created two "threads", now when the process is terminated, the two "threads"/processes that are associated with the process will also be terminated.

Where the information about the "threads"/processes that are associated with a process (that created them) is stored?

Answer (score 3):

The informations are stored in memory in the [task structure called `task_struct`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/sched.h?h=v4.16#n524) associated to each process/thread. All those informations are as usual made available in the pseudo-filesystem `/proc` as described in [`man 5 proc`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/proc.5.en.html#Files_and_directories).

When a process is killed and will disappear, the kernel just parses in memory the list of threads associated to the process (conveniently visible in `/proc/[pid]/task/`) to kill them.

The process/thread representation model in linux doesn't separate much between process and thread, they are all tasks. For example they share the same task namespace, as seen in `/proc/` which organizes *pid* (process id) or *tid* (thread id) the same. But there are differences, eg [getpid()](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/getpid.2.en.html) will return the thread's *pid*, while [gettid](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/gettid.2.en.html)() will return the thread's *tid*. They can return different values when a thread call them.

Relevant to the question, are those pseudo-files mapping to *task_struct* contents:

- > `/proc/[pid]/task/`
  >
  > This is a directory that contains one subdirectory for each thread in
  >   the process. The name of each subdirectory is the numerical thread ID
  >   ([tid]) of the thread (see gettid(2)). Within each of these
  >   subdirectories, there is a set of files with the same names and
  >   contents as under the /proc/[pid] directories. For attributes that are
  >   shared by all threads, the contents for each of the files under the
  >   task/[tid] subdirectories will be the same as in the corresponding
  >   file in the parent /proc/[pid] directory (e.g., in a multithreaded
  >   process, all of the task/[tid]/cwd files will have the same value as
  >   the /proc/[pid]/cwd file in the parent directory, since all of the
  >   threads in a process share a working directory). For attributes that
  >   are distinct for each thread, the corresponding files under task/[tid]
  >   may have different values (e.g., various fields in each of the
  >   task/[tid]/status files may be different for each thread), or they
  >   might not exist in /proc/[pid] at all. In a multithreaded process, the
  >   contents of the /proc/[pid]/task directory are not available if the
  >   main thread has already terminated (typically by calling
  >   pthread_exit(3)).
- `/proc/[pid]/status`

  > Tgid: Thread group ID (i.e., Process ID).

  This pseudo-file has a *Tgid* entry, the same value for all threads of a process (aka the *tid*'s *pid*).

More informations can be seen in `man 7 pthreads` with a description of the current [NPTL](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/pthreads.7.en.html#NPTL) [implementation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/nptl.7.en.html).

Answer (score -1):

Every thread, except for the first (init) has a parent thread.  You can see the relationship best using the f flag to ps, this way: "ps faux" (no quotes).

Answer (score -1):

```
/bin/ps -eo pid,nlwp,tid,args -L
```